# vimrc set highlight mode

Tags: vim

I have the following in my .vimrc file:

```
version 6.0

" set highlight mode
set highlight=8b,@-,db,es,lb,mb,M-,nu,rs,sr,tb,vr,ws
```

Which was largely borrowed from [here](http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax/myvimrc).

I don't understand what this line does:

```
set highlight=8b,@-,db,es,lb,mb,M-,nu,rs,sr,tb,vr,ws
```

I spent a few hours trying to figure out why my line numbers were not conforming to my colorscheme, and have traced it back to this line. If I remove the `nu` from the list, my line numbers start highlighting correctly. I can't find any documentation explaining what any of those two-character patterns mean. Changing or removing the other ones does not seem to affect anything obvious.

Can someone please point me to some documentation that explains what's going on here?

Edit: I read the :help highlight page in Vim, and could not find anything explaining this syntax. If it exists in help, could someone please tell me how to find the relevant section?

Comment: No, you didn't search. `:help 'highlight'`.

Comment: @Downvoter, please leave a comment explaining how I could improve this question.

Comment: You asked to be pointed to the relevant documentation, `:help 'highlight'` is *exactly* what you asked and it has all the info you need.

Comment: @romainl I just read through the `:help highlight` page again and I don't see anything in that documentation explaining what `db`, `M-`, `@-`, etc. are. I would *really* appreciate it if you could quote the relevant part that explains these two-character codes, because I honestly am just not seeing it. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: It's `:help 'highlight'`, **with the quotes**, not `:help highlight`.

Comment: @romainl Ohhhh. Thank you so much! That's **exactly** what I was looking for. If you post as an answer I'll happily accept, otherwise I can just delete the question if you don't think it will help someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was in the comments, [`:help 'highlight'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27highlight%27) has your answers.
Each argument is a pair of type-mode parameters.

The meaning of each of the pairs you listed is:

```
8b special characters for :map (eg <cr>) are bold
@- ~ characters after eof, along with some other special symbols, are not formatted
db directories are bold
es errors are standout
lb last search results are bold
mb more-prompt (when messages take up more than the screen) is bold
M- current mode (eg insert) is not formatted
nu line number is underlined
rs enter and y/n prompts are standout
sr status line of current window is reverse
tb titles of options (eg from :set all) are bold
vr visual highlighting is reverse
ws warnings are standout
```

If you wanted to customise these options, here's the meaning of each possible value for the mode parameter (second character):

```
r   reverse
i   italic
b   bold
s   standout
u   underline
c   undercurl
n   no highlighting
-   no highlighting
:   use a highlight group
```

I won't go into detail for all the possible type parameters (first character), but you can find them in the [previously mentioned help page](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27highlight%27).

Comment: Could you perhaps explain the difference between `:help highlight` and `:help 'highlight'`?

Comment: The help file have a specific notation for different parts of the help. `:help highlight` is general textual topics about highlighting. `:help 'highlight'` is about the option called "highlight". See `:help help-context`.